# How to pull out data from session in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I have the following data from `print_r($_SESSION)`:

```
Array (
[totalprice] => 954
[cart] => Array (
      [115] => Array (
          [name] => MÅNESKINN
          [price] => 268.00
          [count] => 1 )
      [80] => Array (
          [name] => DELFINLEK  
          [price] => 268.00
          [count] => 1 )
      [68] => Array (
          [name] => OPPDAGELSEN
          [price] => 418.00
          [count] => 1 )
      )
[shipping] => 65 )
```

Now I want to pull out all the price 268.00 and 418.00 from this session.

How can I do it?

I tried `$_SESSION['cart']['price']`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$_SESSION['cart'] is an array. If you need only one row - it would be

```
$_SESSION['cart'][115]['price']
```

But you'd better walk through array:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item){
    echo $item['price'];
}
```